# Way to add rectangles to get the bounds of all the rectangles

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to add a grid of rectangles together so that you can get a "container" rectangle (the bounds) of all the rectangles put together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [union](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html#union%28%29) function from the [Rectangle](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Rectangle.html) class

> Union :
>   Adds two rectangles together to create a new Rectangle object, by filling in the horizontal and vertical space between the two rectangles.